# Live Tweeting NECSS

Tags: discussion, skepticism, conference

FYI, I will be at the [North East Conference on Science and Skepticism (NECSS)](http://necss.org/).  I will have my tablet with me, and assuming the wireless is good, I will be live tweeting the event.  I will be using a hashtag of #NECSS.  You can also follow me at [@LarianLeQuella](https://twitter.com/LarianLeQuella).  If you have any specific things you'd like to see from me at the conference, please let me know, and I will see what I can do to honor your request.

Comment: I haven't seen the line up of skeakers, but what about getting some of them to divulge their facebook and twitter accounts so we can follow them?

Comment: Jason, I didn't want to bug them in that manner.  If they are on those sites publicly, you should be able to find them.

Comment: Ah, I understand.  Looks like you were a total twit, erm, tweeter.  :)

Comment: Did you meet @Aarthi?

Comment: @Sklivvz yes I did.  She was wonderful and a lot of fun to hang out with. <3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First day's worth of tweets, these are in reverse order.

**At Stimulus Response (A night of improv and science)**

> DC Comics needs to create Dr. Success as a new super-hero.
>
> Jay Novella's superpower: being an asshole. #NECSS
>
> The abstract connections of the brain are so intertwined that one
>   can't say they're visual or auditory. It's all in there #NECSS
>
> Listening to two awesome neuroscientists talk, and it's just amazing!
>   Wish you were here. #NECSS
>
> Creativity being in a specific part of the brain are totally false -
>   Steven Novella #NECSS
>
> Do you ever think that you see art totally different than the artist
>   intended, and they're okay with that? #NECSS
>
> Sitting here hearing George play, wonder what a George Hrab and Marian
>   Call concert would be like? Awesome! #NECSS
>
> As pattern seeking creatures, even improvisatioanl works makes you see
>   patterns that really aren't there! #NECSS
>
> I think George is using his iPad as an actual instrument. :) #NECSS
>
> For as visual as humans are, it's amazing the effect sound has on us.
>   #NECSS
>
> It's sort of freaky tweeting, and then looking over at someone reading
>   your tweet! #NECSS
>
> I think that sometimes the creation of art is sometimes more moving
>   than the finished product. #NECSS
>
> Hopefully I got thos "live tweeting" thing right. #NECSS
>
> George gets several instruments at once going. Cool effect. #NECSS
>
> Visually I find myself watching the actions of the painter, but
>   George's music totally sets the mood. #NECSS
>
> George Hrab helps make art ant FIT. #NECSS Stimulus and response

**Workshops**

> Classic Rhetoric for Modern Writers is another recommended reading
>   item. #NECSS
>
> The authority of your character will sometimes carry the argument, so
>   learn the art or rhetoric. #NECSS
>
> While skeptics aren't swayed by appeal to authority or emotion, many
>   people ARE! #NECSS
>
> Ray Hyman's "Proper Criticism" should be required reading for
>   everyone, in particular skeptics. #NECSS
>
> Skepticism is not science. The tools and practices belong to all
>   disciplines. #NECSS
>
> Bob likes the word "lepadoptarology" which I know is misspelled. #NECSS
>
> Silly questions never answered are a common trope of shows such as
>   ancient aliens. #NECSS
>
> Numerous spurious and flawed quotes from apparent authorities are
>   rampant, and even reach popular media. #NECSS
>
> "Don't believe everything you read on the internet." Abraham Lincoln #NECSS
>
> Sensational Skepticism: Bob Blaskiewicz and Marc Barnhill. Even the
>   humanities have critical thinking! #NECSS
>
> Kitty Mervine gets a special mention at a workshop. #NECSS
>
> If a child asks you why, instead of answering it, do an experiment. #NECSS
>
> Raising a critical thinker: be curious, be respectful, be wrong, be
>   available, be an example. #NECSS
>
> Think. Question. Grow. Great motto for Camp Inquiry. #NECSS
>
> Camp Inquiry workshop. Started with a fun game of "change if you ever" #NECSS
>
> Do you send out stuff to the world? Do you have RSS? Without RSS, you
>   may be talking to an empty room. #NECSS
>
> The shittiest thing in the real world is better than the perfect
>   production that only exists in your mind. #NECSS
>
> As with anything in life, the secret to success is CONSISTENCY.
>   Podcasts, blogs, etc. Showing up is half the battle. #NECSS
>
> You can do a subset of a subset of a topic as a niche and be
>   successful. #NECSS
>
> Your social media venture could become like Audrey II in terms of
>   eating time. #NECSS
>
> They are talking about podcasting, but it can apply to any social
>   media in principle. #NECSS
>
> Steven Novella and George Hrab talking about using social media to
>   change the world. #NECSS
>
> Rational inquiry is not debate. Winnow the information towards the
>   facts and evidence. #NECSS
>
> Skeptical inquiry has done more for human advancement than any doctor
>   or philanthropist. #NECSS
>
> Our brains bullshit us all the time. "A bet is a tax on bullshit."
>   Have convictions. #NECSS
>
> Tweeting from a small device, please forgive typos. :) #NECSS
>
> Center for Applied Rationality! Look them up. #NECSS "earn good
>   cognitive habits.
>
> We have associations that tend to over ride the facts for real policy
>   decisions. #NECSS
>
> Sphexishness: automatically following rules even if there is no
>   benefit. #NECSS Do humans do that? Sadly yes.
>
> First workshop at #NECSS starts off with the Sphex! Fascinating
>   evolutionary story!
>
> #NECSS checked in! Workshops for the first day.

Answer (score 2):

Day two (although I may tweet a bit at the Drinking Skeptically event, however beware even worse typing and typos!):

> First day wrapped up. Simon was very dynamic recounting the story of
>   the Big Bang theory. Not the show. #NECSS
>
> Alexander Freidman actually came up with the idea of the Big Bang
>   before Lemaitre #NECSS
>
> Even though you lose precision with analogies, you can still bring
>   someone in to your narrative #NECSS
>
> Reassure people that they don't need to give up anything they hold
>   dear to accept a scientific position #NECSS
>
> To evoke emotion get the story to be relateable to the
>   reader/listener. Show things as a journey #NECSS
>
> Ask questions to lead people down a path towards a logical conclusion
>   #NECSS
>
> Theory of mind is the contextual tool for enabling the communication
>   #NECSS
>
> Science is about doubt and not being afraid of not knowing. Need to be
>   comfortable with best approximation #NECSS
>
> To advance skepticism we should use the same language we use at
>   conferences with those we talk to #NECSS
>
> Skeptic gatherings tend to be much more open and intimate when we talk
>   to each other #NECSS
>
> Does the metaphor of going to war hurt the skeptic movement. No tired
>   tropes #NECSS
>
> Use the same tools the charlatans use, the emotional engagement and
>   anecdotal story to capture #NECSS
>
> Storytelling as a tool for skepticism #NECSS
>
> Q&A, always dangerous: sometimes that long rambling story isn't
>   actually a question #NECSS
>
> Really tough fact or fiction. Audience pretty evenly split. #NECSS
>
> Skepticism is in a Catch-22 in debunking woo woo, and not give more
>   life to the woo woo movement #NECSS
>
> Apparently woo woo spreads faster than rationality #NECSS
>
> Scientists are crunching data from twitter. The data is interesting,
>   and depressing #NECSS
>
> Latest batshit insane crazy: vaccines can make you gay... #NECSS
>
> Type 1x supernovas are interesting and entertaining to me (and Bob and
>   Steven) #NECSS
>
> Jay Novella loves memes. And now there are SGU generated memes. #NECSS
>
> Add your own words. Bob picked quantum. I expect energy to be added.
>   #NECSS
>
> Check out the 7 misused terms in Scientific American. Skeptic made the
>   list #NECSS
>
> When did colloquialisms water down scientific ideas? Such as the word
>   theory #NECSS
>
> Steven Novella is the energizer bunny of skepticism. #NECSS
>
> The danger of eating anywhere near the conference: they are all
>   slammed #NECSS
>
> Looking forward to an afternoon of SGU, storytelling, and the Big
>   Bang. #NECSS
>
> This seems to be an argument about degrees and nuances which we are
>   always struggling to refine and changes all the time #NECSS
>
> This discussion would probably make more sense if I had read the
>   online discussion #NECSS
>
> "We can do better than that." Should be a motto for any endeavor
>   #NECSS
>
> Is the transition between science and philosophy smooth, or is the
>   empirical to philosophical transition more abrupt #NECSS
>
> What degree does science play in the establishment of morality #NECSS
>
> Part of the live audience for Rationally Speaking podcast. Get it once
>   posted. #NECSS
>
> Okay this will be fun: a live discussion/debate between Shermer and
>   Pigliucci #NECSS
>
> Democracies are generally the "ask first" principle writ large #NECSS
>
> When gay marriage finally becomes a right, christians will take credit
>   for it, like they have for emancipation #NECSS
>
> Heady presentations on morality in our world. Should lead to
>   interesting conversations at #NECSS
>
> The biocultural evolutionary pyramid looks a lot like Maslow's
>   hierarchy of needs #NECSS
>
> The moral arc of science bends towards justice, freedom, and liberty
>   #NECSS
>
> Reflective equilibrium: bringing more coherence to your beliefs #NECSS
>
> Vampire bats exhibit reciprocal altruism. Human behavior is generally
>   not unique #NECSS
>
> We know how morality evolved, but not always what IS right or wrong
>   #NECSS
>
> Trolley dilemma research is very pervasive, if you push the fat guy,
>   you may be a sociopath #NECSS
>
> Pigliucci goes Mony Python instead of Douglas Adams for the meaning of
>   life #NECSS
>
> Skeptics don't have a lock on the truth, beware of your brain #NECSS
>
> You can have a very clear memory of something, but still be wrong
>   #NECSS
>
> Latenight commercials use "anchoring" to manipulate the perceived
>   value of a product #NECSS
>
> Causes us to act more like an attorney than a scientist in reaching
>   our conclusion, unconsciously #NECSS
>
> Motivated reasoning can influence our views of ourself to be more
>   optimistic than warranted #NECSS
>
> Touch creates a context of trust. It can improve chances of success in
>   many endeavors #NECSS
>
> Despite protestations, there is a significant effect on elections
>   based on looks alone #NECSS
>
> Once context has been established, you can't go back in many illusions
>   #NECSS
>
> Your brain is fascinating for vision, it fills in A LOT of information
>   that can end up tricking us #NECSS
>
> We can now look inside the skull and watch it work without cutting
>   your head open #NECSS
>
> Social neuroscience is a new field as a result of the advances of
>   technology #NECSS
>
> Starting off #NECSS being part of an experiment run by Leonard
>   Mlodinow
>
> Just mention Deepak Chopra and you get a laugh. #NECSS
>
> Jamie Ian Swiss kicks off #NECSS
>
> Not TOO hung over for the next day of #NECSS :)

Answer (score 1):

And day three:

> And a final thank you to http://skeptics.stackexchange.com  #NECSS
>
> And a special thank you to my twitter followers, old and new #NECSS
>
> Well, that's the end of #NECSS! Wonderful time. Thanks NYC Skeptics and all.
>
> It's not "what are the odds of this specific thing" but "what are the odds of this general thing" #NECSS
>
> The most amazing coincidence of all would be complete absence of all coincidences. #NECSS
>
> Describing the world is an olympic task between simplifiers and complicators. We need both #NECSS
>
> Great mathematically based jokes in this presentation #NECSS
>
> Most people's ability to discuss probability are limited to 50/50 or one in a million #NECSS
>
> Interesting etymology of the terms used in mathematics and statistics #NECSS
>
> John Allen Paulos is next at #NECSS
>
> "Our internet law is based on a 1858 manservant running to London." @SLSingh #NECSS
>
> It's a sign the core of a alt-med association is rotten that they don't actually challenge the claims #NECSS
>
> Jamy gets cheeky about happy endings. "We'll cut that in post." #NECSS
>
> "I know a lot of law for a particle physicist." @SLSingh #NECSS
>
> Damn, screwed that up... Let me try again... #NECSS
>
> "I know a lot of law for. Particle physicist." @SLSingh #NECSS
>
> Make sure to support the Libel Reform movement Simon is leading. #NECSS
>
> Simon Singh interview by Jamy Ian Swiss #NECSS
>
> Oh, that Sean Carroll quote is spot on! #NECSS At heart, science is the quest for awesome -
>
> Skeptical quotes put to music and song! #NECSS
>
> Celebrate and elevate what we have evidence for. #NECSS
>
> A skeptical round. Normal food. Wow, haw do they think of this? #NECSS
>
> Can't tweet, this is just all sorts of awesome! #NECSS
>
> Next slide please. Awesome. #NECSS
>
> Science Fair, an opera singer's lovesong to science http://hai-ting.com  #NECSS
>
> A musical interlude with Matthew Schickele and Hai-Ting Chinn #NECSS
>
> Riveting stage presence and great talk by @jamyianswiss about the history of the Skeptic movement & war against irrationality #NECSS
>
> "I'm a philosopher, I have no problem with shameful conjecture." @mpigliucci #NECSS
>
> That was a narrow escape. Kudos to Jim Holt for making sense of that! #NECSS
>
> Uh oh, here comes a speech! #NECSS
>
> These questions are best pursued at 2am, in a dorm room, with a bong. #NECSS
>
> Q&A: good reminder to have a question, not a speech. :) #NECSS
>
> The participatory universe is like a bad acid trip! #NECSS
>
> Reality seems to be an infinite, fuzzy, incomplete mess in effect. #NECSS
>
> Derek Parfit profile in the New Yorker is recommended reading for those interested in the philosophical questions of existence #NECSS
>
> Why should we think that simple things are more probable than complex things? #NECSS
>
> Believers seem to have a very weird idea of what counts as an explanation #NECSS
>
> "God must be puzzled by his own existence." Jim Holt #NECSS
>
> Chaotic inflation (which has ample evidence) actually has implications for the multiverse theory #NECSS
>
> Good, Massimo is addressing the fine tuning fallacy. I frikkin hate that fallacy. Read Victor Stenger #NECSS
>
> The explanation that the universe was created by a physicist hacker explains why this universe is so messy #NECSS
>
> Simulation hypothesis = god for geeks #NECSS
>
> Bust=but... Damn typos
>
> Swinburn has an argument for god, bust it seems based on fine tuning fallacy... #NECSS
>
> Massimo quotes Hitchhiker's Guide to the Galaxy. Well done sir. #NECSS
>
> Now for a live session of Rationally Speaking #NECSS
>
> Jamy's last words particularly resonated with me: "Have a good time doing it." #NECSS
>
> The job isn't done and it will never be done just because we're tired. #NECSS
>
> What's the harm? It's a loss of opportunity for something real that could be better used to help #NECSS
>
> Jami Ian Swiss: in skepticism, "NO SACRED COWS ALLOWED!" Skepticism is a method of inquiry, not a position. #NECSS
>
> "Anyone can be fooled!" #NECSS Yes, even you! Don't blame the victim.
>
> Scientists aren't trained to detect deliberate deception #NECSS nature is inherently honest (maybe neutral is a better word)
>
> Magicians are honest liars. #NECSS Glad to have so many as part of the skeptical movement
>
> If only Jamy Ian Swiss was passionate about skepticism. ;) #NECSS
>
> Skepticism is actually a branch of consumer protection! Think about that a moment. #NECSS
>
> Scientific skepticism is a way of thinking, not what to think. #NECSS. A common theme
>
> "Why is there a skeptic movement" by Daniel Loxton READ IT. #NECSS
>
> I encourage you to look up Randi's Project Alpha. #NECSS
>
> Righteous Indignation: skepticism is not only about truth, but what is right or morally wrong (causing harm) #NECSS
>
> "When you offer physical evidence of supernatural claims, you tend to get caught." #NECSS
>
> Relationship between magicians, skepticism, and critical thinking #NECSS
>
> Reginald Scott wrote "Discovery of Witchcraft" in Elizabethan England. An early skeptic #NECSS
>
> Jamy's foundational book for skepticism: Demon Haunted World. No surprise :) #NECSS
>
> Next up for #NECSS: Jamy Ian Swiss. Didn't we just see him? Look forward to him introducing himself. :)
>
> "If you thought this stuff was real, you'd be a congregation, not an audience." #NECSS
>
> Inappropriate rationality: humorous stories from Jamy #NECSS
>
> Magic often renders the audience psychologically transparent, and they don't know it #NECSS
>
> Woot, Jamy Ian Swiss is quoting Einstein and doing magic before lunch #NECSS
>
> "We all have a bit of psychopathy." Milgram experiment: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8olVHKgIBXc&sns=em … #NECSS” "We all go a little mad sometimes."-Norman Bates
>
> Insults overheard at #NECSS: "You lack sooo much empathy, you would find a way to kill all 6 people in a trolley experiment."
>
> Basically convince population that targets are non-human (i.e. Nazi Germany) #NECSS
>
> Wow, great question from the audience: can the psychopathic behavior transmitable? #NECSS
>
> Uh oh Q&A time: remember to start with a who, what, where, when, why, how... #NECSS
>
> Cartman (South Park) is one of the best representations of a psychopath in media #NECSS
>
> Sociopath and psychopath are the same, just different connotations to the words #NECSS
>
> Are any psychological diagnosis cultural phenomenon? Maybe, depends on how you look for it. #NECSS
>
> Psychopathy isn't a cultural phenomenon, it's a brain phenomenon. #NECSS
>
> If you have symptoms of delusions and you are religious, is that the same diagnosis? #NECSS
>
> DBS is inserted into the white matter of the brain because it seems to be the nexus for communication #NECSS
>
> DBS is replacing the irreversible procedure of making lesions #NECSS
>
> Pharmecalogical manipulation is reaching it's limit with what we can do, because evolutions is sloppy. #NECSS
>
> Currently the Deep Brain Stimulation mechanism isn't fully understood, but they are working on understanding #NECSS
>
> Deep brain stimulation, like a pacemaker for the brain for OCD patients. Novel stuff! #NECSS
>
> For some, it's difficult to unlearn a behavior even when the contingencies change. Frontal lobe stuff #NECSS
>
> Heather's research is the imaging of compulsive and impulsive brains. Compared borderline patients with lesions #NECSS
>
> We need a placeholder for talking about a lot of stuff. Simply semantics still. #NECSS
>
> Psychiatry is in a stage of describing what we see, all fields go through these stages of understanding #NECSS
>
> Heather thinks the DSM may become obsolete in the future #NECSS
>
> Psychopathy isn't generally treatable as a personality disorder. And most think they are fine. #NECSS
>
> Must take data from many and varied sources before making a diagnosis and applying a label #NECSS
>
> White=while dang typos... #NECSS
>
> White 1% of general population is psychopathic, 4-5% of CEOs are! Explains a lot #NECSS
>
> When you infuse your decisions with emotion, you actually tend to make better decisions #NECSS
>
> If you have no psychopathy traits, you are a milquetoast but where on the spectrum are you? #NECSS
>
> Psychopathy may actually be the most pleasant of mental illnesses since there is no remorse #NECSS
>
> There is a test to determine if you are a psychopath! #NECSS
>
> Steven Novella has the most appearances of any presenter at #NECSS :)
>
> Psychopathy panel next: fascinating topic. We all probably know one. #NECSS
>
> Ask "believers" if they want to know more as a strategy to talk to them. Use humor. #NECSS
>
> Skepticism isn't about the facts, but the pleasure of finding things out #NECSS
>
> Look up technovation challenge and support them #NECSS
>
> If the books actually have "the truth" why are there revised editions? #NECSS
>
> Many traditions have positive aspects, but there can be stress from the irrational aspects #NECSS
>
> Authoritarian: that's just the way it is, don't ask about it #NECSS
>
> Revealed truth: they have the ONE TRUE answer #NECSS
>
> Smorgasbord: all viewpoints are valid #NECSS
>
> Three types of people in the non-skeptical community: #NECSS
>
> A lonely skeptic in a believer's world: a talk I can identify with. Deborah Berebichez #NECSS
>
> Now that you know the term of sciencey, I bet you'll see it everywhere! #NECSS
>
> Science in the world. Kids aren't taught how science will solve the problems of the world #NECSS
>
> Outreach & education: after 10 years of trying, they give up on scientifical stuff and go spiritual woo #NECSS
>
> When purveyors of woo present locally, go and ask pre-prepared questions #NECSS
>
> Products, especially in health and beauty, have all sorts of sciencey stuff #NECSS
>
> Did you know that in 2012 the world DIDN'T end? #NECSS
>
> Ghost hunter books: no references or citations! That's a clue! Cargo cult science. #NECSS
>
> Sham inquiry: start with the conclusion and look for confirming results #NECSS
>
> They value science, but they have no idea how it really works. #NECSS
>
> Look up scientifical in the urban dictionary: that's what these ARIG do #NECSS
>
> Not only are they fooling themselves, but they are also fooling the public #NECSS
>
> Sharon stopped counting these ARIG when she got to 1300. Over half think they use science #NECSS
>
> ARIG amateur research and investigation group: not associated with any academic group #NECSS
>
> Putting "sciencey" groups under scrutiny for the first time as a study #NECSS
>
> Sharon talking about people that use "sciencey" ideas and terms #NECSS
>
> Sharon Hill first up as the hangover speaker. And I see her "Thor's Hammer" necklace #NECSS
>
> Exciting line-up for today's #NECSS auditorium filling up and excitement building
>
> Small world moment: met fellow @DAoC players from Sweden at #NECSS
>
> Not too hung over even after drinking skeptically #NECSS
>
> For a city that never sleeps, NYC is quiet on sunday morning #NECSS